# Raising PropertyChanged events from an update loop (winRT/C++)

Tags: multithreading, thread-safety, windows-runtime, c++-winrt, winui-3

The following code creates an update thread that is supposed to notify the view every 10ms.

```
    DataVM::DataVM()
    {
        Update = UpdateLoop();
    }
    
    IAsyncAction DataVM::UpdateLoop()
    {
        co_await resume_background();
        while ( true )
        {
            std::this_thread::sleep_for( std::chrono::milliseconds( 10 ) );
            RaisePropertyChanged( L"SomeProperty" );
        }
    }
```

The issue: Something goes wrong when `RaisePropertyChanged` is called and the thread stops. Inspecting the `Update` object it shows `Status=Error` after `RaisePropertyChanged` has been called once. Without the call it keeps running. There is also nothing wrong with my impl of `RaisePropertyChanged`, it works as intended in other places.

Questions:

1. How do I go about debugging things like this? Where would I see the `Error` occurring?
2. How do I correctly call `RaisePropertyChanged` so that my code works as intended?
3. Other/better ways to update on a regular basis? (This one seems pretty easy, though, if only it worked)

Comment: I'm pretty sure that you need to call `RaisePropertyChanged` on the UI thread. [Advanced concurrency and asynchrony with C++/WinRT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/cpp-and-winrt-apis/concurrency-2) explains how to do that. Also make sure to read [Safely accessing the `this` pointer in a class-member coroutine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/cpp-and-winrt-apis/weak-references#safely-accessing-the-this-pointer-in-a-class-member-coroutine).

Answer (score 0):

A simple way seems to be:

```
    IAsyncAction DataVM::UpdateLoop()
    {
        winrt::apartment_context ui_thread;

        while ( true )
        {
            co_await resume_background();
            co_await std::chrono::milliseconds( 10 );
            co_await ui_thread;
            RaisePropertyChanged( L"SomeProperty" );
        }

    }
```

where one 'captures' the UI thread and regularly passes control back. Not sure what happens when this goes out of scope, though. Might need to do something in the destructor.